# How to hide "open with" option at the time of downloading file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have small requirement for downloading the file, here I would like to hide "open with" option and "Save" should be "Save As", could you please help me,
[image]

Comment: I think this is Firefox-specific? Not sure Javascript has any power on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is firefox relating. I don't think it's possible to change the options you're trying to change. However you can change the download action which might be useful to yourself. Please see below

This will not affect media embedded in a web page - only links to the files themselves.

1. Click the menu button [image] and choose `Options`
2. Select the `Applications` panel.
3. The Applications panel will display. Select the type of file for which you want to change the default action.
4. The Action column will give you a drop-down menu, with options on action to take, whenever you click that type of file.

[image]

- **Always ask:** will prompt you to select what action you want Firefox to take when you click on that type of file. This can be useful if Firefox is automatically saving a file type or is always opening it with a certain program and you want to be asked what to do.
- **Save File:** will always save the file to your computer using the Downloads window, whenever you click that type of file.
- Open the file with an application or plugin of your choosing.

  5. Click `Ok` to close the options window after making changes]

Further reading **[here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file)**